# values of commun column in A replaced by that in B with function merge in SAS

Tags: sas

I want merge two tables, but they have 2 columns in commun, and i do not want value of var1 in A replaced by that in B, if we don't use `drop` or `rename`,  does anyone know it? 
I can fix it with sql but just curious with Merge!

```
data a;
infile datalines;
input id1 $ id2 $ var1;
datalines;
1 a 10
1 b 10
2 a 10
2 b 10
;
run;
/* create table B */
data b;
infile datalines;
input id1 $ id2 $ var1  var2;
datalines;
1 a 30 50
2 b 30 50
;
run; 
/* Marge A and B */
data c;
merge a (in=N) b(in=M);
if N;
by id1;
run;
```

but what i like is:

```
data C;
infile datalines;
input id1 $ id2 $ var1 var2;
datalines;
1 a 10 50
1 b 10 50
2 a 10 50
2 b 10 50
;
run;
```

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for?  Just change the order of the datasets in the MERGE statement.  Put the dataset whose values you want to "win" last.

Answer (score 1):

Use rename

```
data c; 
 merge a (in=N) b(in=M rename=(var1=var1_2));
 by id1;
 if N;
run;
```

If you don't want to use rename / drop etc., then you could just flip the merge order such that the datasets whose var1 should be retained overwrites the other:

```
data c; 
 merge b (in=M) a(in=N);
 by id1;
 if N;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the data step loads data from the datasets mentioned it does it in the order that they appear on the MERGE (or SET or UPDATE) statement.  So if you are merging two dataset and the BY variables match values then the record from the first is loaded and the record from the second is loaded, overwriting the values read from the first.

For 1 to 1 matching you can just change the order that the datasets are mentioned.

```
merge b(in=M) a(in=N) ;
```

If you really want the variables defined in the output dataset in the order they appear in A then add a SET statement that the compiler will process but that can never execute before your MERGE statement.

```
if 0 then set a b ;
```

If you are doing a 1 to many matching then you might have other trouble since when a dataset stops contributing values to the current BY group then SAS does not re-read the last observation. In that case you will have to use some combination of RENAME=, DROP= or KEEP= dataset options.

In PROC SQL when you have duplicate names for selected columns (and are trying to create an output dataset instead of report) then SAS ignores the second copy of the named variable.  So in a sense it is the reverse of what happens with the MERGE statement.